# Counting frequency of elements in a numpy array within a certain range of values?

Tags: python, list, numpy, counter, frequency

I've spent way too long on this problem that I figure should only be taking me a few minutes to figure out. I have an array called i with ~400 numbers in it between 1-21.  I want to count the frequency of each of these numbers 1-21 in the data. I ALSO want to limit this range to be between 1-16 and exclude the numbers above 16.

Here's what I got to work, but it's extremely clunky and inefficient. I feel like there must be a way to shorten this a lot. I need to be able to take the frequency outputs and have them in a sorted array called nvals that I can use for subsequent calculations.

```
i=bin_numDM+(bin_numF-1)*fbins

ones= 0
twos=0
threes=0
fours=0
fives=0
sixes=0
sevens=0
eights=0
nines=0
tens=0
elevens=0
twelves=0
thirteens=0
fourteens=0
fifteens=0
sixteens=0

for item in i:
    if item ==1:
        ones = ones + 1
    if item==2:
        twos=twos+1
    if item==3:
        threes=threes+1
    if item==4:
        fours=fours+1
    if item==5:
        fives=fives+1
    if item==6:
        sixes=sixes+1
    if item==7:
        sevens=sevens+1
    if item==8:
        eights=eights+1
    if item==9:
        nines=nines+1
    if item==10:
        tens=tens+1
    if item==11:
        elevens=elevens+1
    if item==12:
        twelves=twelves+1
    if item==13:
        thirteens=thirteens+1
    if item==14:
        fourteens=fourteens+1
    if item==15:
        fifteens=fifteens+1
    if item==16:
        sixteens=sixteens+1 
nvals=[ones,twos,threes,fours,fives,sixes,sevens,eights,nines,tens,elevens,twelves,thirteens,fourteens,fifteens,sixteens]
```

I also tried:

```
unique, frequency=np.unique(i,return_counts=True)
count=np.asarray((unique,frequency))
```

Which works, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to restrict this to a range of i values between 1-16.

Any advice? :)

Comment: Have you tried filtering the original array before counting: `filtered = i[(i>0) & (i<=16)]`?

Comment: Why do you need to restrict the results to the range of 1 to 16? In any case, either filter before counting (e.g. `v, c = np.unique(a[a<=16], return_counts=True)` or after (`m = v <= 16; v[m], c[m]`. Note: for higher speed (no sorting done) you can use `pandas`. For a solution with no other package than std library, use `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for depends on if you want to use libraries or not. If you are using numpy arrays, then

```
val, count = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
```

is the way to go. Otherways, you should avoid calling `if` for every possible outcome. Rather, you can use a dictionnary to store your item instances:

```
l = [1,2,2,3,5]
solution = {i:0 for i in range(16)}
for item in l:
    if item in solution:
        solution[item] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove elements which you want to exclude first, then do the counting.

```
import numpy as np

i = np.arange(1, 22)

filtered_i = np.delete(i, np.where(i > 16))

unique, frequency=np.unique(filtered_i, return_counts=True)
count=np.asarray((unique, frequency))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [numpy.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
import numpy as np
i = np.random.randint(1,22,400)
unique, counts = np.unique(i, return_counts=True)
ocurrences = dict(zip(unique, counts))
result = {k:v for k, v in occurences.items() if 0<k<17}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few equivalent ways, along with timing. They all share the same result presentation: a sorted `dict` containing `{value: count}`.

```py
def f0(a):
    v, c = np.unique(a[a <= 16], return_counts=True)
    return dict(zip(v, c))

def f1(a):
    v, c = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
    m = v <= 16
    return dict(zip(v[m], c[m]))

def f2(a):
    return dict(sorted(Counter(a[a <= 16]).items()))

def f3(a):
    return pd.value_counts(a[a <= 16]).sort_index().to_dict()

def f4(a):
    return pd.value_counts(a).sort_index().loc[1:16].to_dict()
```

Test:

```py
np.random.seed(0)  # reproducibility
n = 1_000_000
a = np.random.randint(1, 22, n)

>>> f0(a)
{1: 47533,
 2: 47765,
 3: 47145,
 4: 47764,
 5: 47691,
 6: 47414,
 7: 47480,
 8: 47627,
 9: 48080,
 10: 47502,
 11: 47970,
 12: 48020,
 13: 47854,
 14: 47596,
 15: 47578,
 16: 47222}
```

And:

```py
%timeit f0(a)
# 29.1 ms ± 32.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit f1(a)
# 32.8 ms ± 36.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit f2(a)
# 93.8 ms ± 291 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit f3(a)
# 10 ms ± 29.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit f4(a)
# 5.82 ms ± 20.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Indeed. I re-did the timings with the modified answer, and there was no material change.